# Mensagem no Botão Sair - Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms

Preciso de uma mensagem no Botão Sair (utilizarei o `Navigation.PopAsync()`) próximo do que fiz mas que funcione (esse não funciona):

```
//Botão Sair
void BtnSair_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var result = DisplayAlert("Alerta", "Deseja realmente sair?", "Sim", "Não");
   if (result) {Navigation.PopAsync();}  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como pra alguns pode ser útil consegui resolver da seguinte maneira:

```
private async Task BtnSair_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var result = await DisplayAlert("Alerta", "Deseja realmente sair?", "Sim", "Não");

  if (result)
  {
    await Navigation.PopAsync();
  }
}
```

Percebi que o DisplayAlert retorna `Task` e a variável esperava apenas `bool`, então na chamada do botão utilizei `private async Task` e depois `await` onde terá que aguardar retorno.